# i want to get the form data form one gsp and want to access that data in another gsp and want to insert that data in table, how can i do this?

Tags: grails

This is one gsp where i created one form

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="msg_to">To</label>
            <input type="email" id="msg_to" name="msg_to" class="form-control" style="width:500px;" required="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="msg_subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" style="width:500px;"name="msg_subject" required="" maxlength="50">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="msg_body">Body</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="msg_body" style="width: 500px; height: 250px"  name="msg_body" required="" ></textarea>
        </div>

        %{--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>--}%
        <g:actionSubmit value="Send" action="g_Inbox" style="color: #000000"></g:actionSubmit>

    </form>
```

The data of above form must be access to another controller after submit and data should be display in the table form on that another view.

I fetch above data in following action:

```
 def g_Inbox(){

    def msg_to = params.msg_to;
    def msg_subject = params.msg_subject;
    def msg_body = params.msg_body;

    println msg_to
    println msg_subject
    println msg_body


    render(view: 'g_Inbox', model: [m_to : msg_to , m_sub : msg_subject , m_body: msg_body] )
}
```

from here i want to send it to view and want to add in new row of table..

Comment: "access data in other GSP" seems lake classic anti-pattern, bad pattern from JSP, rethink You idea, move data into common place called Model

Comment: do you have any idea of Grails not to mention MVC-pattern at all?

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. What you want to do is very easy with Grails. *But...* you have to do your homework.

## Things to read and digest

### (best served with pizza and iced tea)

1. Groovy Server Pages -
   https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#gsp
2. Controllers - https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllers

Once you understand GSP and controllers, you'll know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simple if You know how it works

```
render(view: 'g_Inbox', model:[params:params])
```

Access the params in gsp by

```
${params.msg_to}
```

and for Another Controller

```
redirect controller:'Controller' action: 'create',params:params
```